# await call crashes but .Result succeeds

Tags: .net, .net-core, async-await, console-application

I have stumbled onto a strange problem...

This is a simple code that just calls an API with await

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<DTO>> GetAll(int Id, string APIPath)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync($"{APIPath}/Contract/GetAll?Id={Id}");
    var responseResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DTO>>(responseResult.ToString());
}
```

When I am debugging and when I step over the `await` line. The application crashes without any exception and the debugging session is ended.

But when I change the `await` to `.Result`, the debugging session continues and keep running normally and even returns the response from the API.

My guess is, that somehow the new thread is not created and the debugging session is finished because of a crash. Any ideas, why?

**UPDATE**
It is a .Net Core Console Application

**UPDATE2**
Not sure how it is helpful, but here is the calling line...

```
var contracts = await _contractAdapter.GetAll(Id, APIPath);
```

Comment: Do not mixed async with blocking calls like `.Result`

Comment: I am not mixing that and that is why asking the question :) When I mix those, the application runs fine...

Comment: Show how `GetAll` is called

Comment: If you run it outside the debugger, what happens? Have tried to had a `try`/`catch` block and see if you catch any exception?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using `await client.GetAsync()`, that's how everyone uses HttpClient. If it failed, people would have noticed since it came out in 2012. What is the actual exception? Post the full exception including the call stack. You can get it easily with `Exception.ToString()`. This will show not only the actual exception but what calls lead to it. It could be that you aren't awaiting the top-level method, or that you have an `async void` call resulting in an orphaned call. `async void` is only meant for fire-and-forget methods.

Comment: BTW `responseResult` is a string, there's no reason to call `responseResult.ToString()`

Comment: I have a try-catch block in the calling function. No exception is caught there... I haven't tried running without debugger. Will update on this after that...

Comment: I tried running without debugging, but it crashes still without any exception anywhere...